# I don't understand a definition of one of the meanings of 途方?

Tags: definitions

From [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/160081/meaning/m0u/%E9%80%94%E6%96%B9/):

> １ 多くの方向。向かう方向。
>
> 「―を失へる敵どもを」〈太平記・一〇〉

I don't understand how 多くの方向 (that I think means "many directions") means the same thing that 向かう方向(that I think means "direction to follow")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, in modern Japanese, 途方 is almost always used in set phrases (途方もない and 途方に暮れる), and it never refers to a physical direction. 太平記 was written in the 14th century. Many other monolingual dictionaries of modern Japanese do not even mention this usage related to physical directions. So I guess the author of goo辞書 thought these old definitions of 途方 (多くの方向 and 向かう方向) are so trivial that they can be crammed into one item.

(By the way, [this page about 太平記](http://cubeaki.dip.jp/taiheiki/taiheiki/taiheiki1-10/taiheiki-10-2.html) translates this part as 途方にくれている...)

Comment: FYI 途方を失ふ means 途方に暮れる.

Comment: As expected, 大辞林 has an entry for it. https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%80%94%E6%96%B9%E3%82%92%E5%A4%B1%E3%81%86-343127

Answer (score 0):

I guess 多く means more likely second definition in this case.

> 多く：分量・数量の多いこと。
>   1. たくさん。「そんなに―食うな」
>   2. おおかた。たいてい。「この本は―学生が読む」

Given the second definition, 多くの方向 means an approximate direction.